# R extract house / street numers from adress string

Tags: r, extract, tidyr

say I have the following data with addresses, i.e. street names. My goal is to separate street names from house numbers.

```
mydf <- tribble(
  ~street,
  "Some Way 10",
  "Shiny Street   12b",
  "Dark Street   from Netflix Movie 17c - 17d",
  "Seasame Street",
  "Dark Alley 15c",
)

mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(street= str_squish(street)) # get rid of whitespace
```

I tried the following

```
sub <- tidyr::extract(mydf, "street", c("street_name_only", "house_number"), "(\\D+)(\\d.*)") %>%
 print(n=5)
```

which works fine, as long as there is a street or house number present. If the string "street" is without a street number, then NAs will show up in the new variable "street_name_only" as well as "house_number", as is the case with "Sesame Street". ( I would like to have "Sesame Street" in the "new_street_column" and ideally "" (empty) in the house_number column, though I could mange the NA in the house_number column afterwards).

Could anybody tell me where I went wrong and how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work:

```
mydf %>% 
    transmute(street_name_only = str_remove(street, '\\d.*'), 
                  house_number = str_extract(street, '\\d.*'))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  street_name_only                  house_number
  <chr>                             <chr>       
1 "Some Way "                       10          
2 "Shiny Street "                   12b         
3 "Dark Street from Netflix Movie " 17c - 17d   
4 "Seasame Street"                  NA          
5 "Dark Alley "                     15c
```

Comment: Yes indeed it does! Thank you very much!  I knew of the functions you used, but I hadn't thought of combining them together!. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::separate` :

```
tidyr::separate(mydf, street, c("street_name_only", "house_number"), 
                '(?=\\d)', extra = 'merge', fill = 'right')

# street_name_only                    house_number
#  <chr>                               <chr>       
#1 "Some Way "                         10          
#2 "Shiny Street   "                   12b         
#3 "Dark Street   from Netflix Movie " 17c - 17d   
#4 "Seasame Street"                    NA          
#5 "Dark Alley "                       15c
```