# extracting just numbers at the front of a string

Tags: r

I need to parse through a list of addresses and remove the ones without street numbers or with PO boxes. I want to create a column, street number, that is just the numbers at the front of the string, and NA if it starts with letters. So for:

```
street<-c("123 fake st", "PO box 12", "fake st unit 2", "123 fake st apt 1")
```

I would want:

```
c(123, NA, NA, 123)
```

I see a lot [of q&a's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635978/r-extract-house-street-numers-from-adress-string) for [subsetting numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings) from a string, but I'm not sure how to do it without pulling in the numbers from the back end too.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to capture the digits (`\\d+`) at the start (`^`) of the string

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(street, "^\\d+"))
[1] 123  NA  NA 123
```

---

Or using `base R` functions with `strsplit`

```
as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(street, " "), `[`, 1))
[1] 123  NA  NA 123
```

or `trimws`

```
as.numeric(trimws(street, whitespace = "\\s+.*"))
[1] 123  NA  NA 123
```

Comment: The `trimws` option is amazing, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In base R we can use `sub` to replace starting from a non number to the end of the string

```
as.numeric(sub("\\D+.*", "", street))

[1] 123  NA  NA 123
```

If you do not know regular expressions, you can use `parse_number` function with `ifelse`. as shown below

```
library(tidyverse)
ifelse(substr(street, 1, 1) %in% 0:9, parse_number(street), NA)
[1] 123  NA  NA 123
```